# TimeSynchronizer too slow for PointCloud2 and LaserScan

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used messaged_filters to sync messages from a pointcloud2 topic and and a laserscan topic, process, and publish it. But the publish rate is too slow for it to be of any use, even without doing anything in the processing bit. About 5-8 seconds for each published.

Does anyone know any alternatives?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58197/timesynchronizer-too-slow-for-pointcloud2-and-laserscan./) by [superawesomepandacat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3651/superawesomepandacat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are the PointCloud2 and LaserScan coming from the same sensor?

If they are from separate sensors, you should try the Approximate timesync policy:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters#Policy-Based_Synchronizer_.5BROS_1.1.2B-.5D

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [superawesomepandacat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3651/superawesomepandacat/) on 2013-03-15**:
They are from separate sensors. I'll let you know if its solved after I try it.